# How could I identify whether given RNA-seq data is paired end or single end

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing

I need to have a RNA-Seq dataset and therefore, I've visited the following site [NCBI-geo C. Elegans](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE64672)

In the Supplemantary file part, I clicked the *SRP/SRP051/SRP051702  ftp* and downloaded ***sra*** file. Then I need to convert it to fastq file format. For this purpose I've heard that there is a sra-toolkit and within it there is  fastq-dump exacutable. However in order to use it, first of all I have to figure out whether my sra file contains paired-end or single-end read data. So my question is that how could I know the type of reads in the dataset (in the first link) ?

Without any information, I used ***--split_files*** flag of ***fastq-dump*** exacutable and it generated two 14 Gb  **(both of them  are exactly 14.346.367.840 bytes)** files and their name are  *SRR1741330_1.fastq* and *SRR1741330_2.fastq* Does it mean my dataset is paired end ?

As an another question (different but related with part 1). In the SRR1741330_1.fastq file, at some lines, sequences contains different characters such as *CCCFFFFFGFHHHGJJJJI#1?FEIGGI*... Before looking into these files, I have thought that these sequence lines should only contain the letters of A,G,T and C . What are these F,H,J,I,#,? etc..

My questions might be trivial and unmeaningful but since I'm a totally new person in this area, I could not understand them.

**EDIT**

**New question**

I wonder one more thing, since its related with previous part of my question I asked it here instead of creating new question. After I generate fastq file with dump_fastq executable, all the sequences are length of 50. Does it because of parameters of the dump_fastq executable or its related with original sra file? In other words, could I increase this length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out whether a dataset was paired-end or single-end, go to SRA, click on a run, and look under "Library". Paired-end datasets will typically have "Layout: paired". Note that people don't always mark this correctly, which causes no end of headaches.

Regarding lines like "CCCFFFFFGFHHHGJJJJI#1?FEIGGI", that's the quality score line. Look at the fastq article in wikipedia for more details.

**Edit:** Regarding the updated portion of your question, no you can not increase this length. The sequences produced by Illumina machines are a fixed length and that length (or whatever length was submitted) is what you're getting. As a general rule, you'll get whatever sequence was updated (unless you forget the --split3 (or whatever it's called) option).

Comment: @Devon_Ryan thanks for your help, by mean go to SRA, I think you refer to sra file that I downloaded from the link I provide above,right?

Comment: Okey, now I found it, it is in the browser

Comment: Exactly, I mean the webpage for a run on the SRA website. The same information is typically available in GEO too (click on one of the samples and read the "Data Processing" section), but it's typically a bit faster to just go to SRA.

Comment: @Devon_Ryan thanks again, could you look at my question again, I've updated  it

Comment: I've updated my reply. The short answer is that you're getting what was uploaded, which is typically all that was sequenced.

Comment: @Devon_Ryan thanks for the last time : ) So, as I understood from your updated answer, rna-seq data was supplied by the length of 50 base pairs read then.

Comment: @stackunderflow Yes, exactly.